# SSH using LDAP credentials is showing perimission denied (public key)

Tags: linux, ldap, linux-networking, openldap, ubuntu-16.04

I have 2 machines (LDAP Server and LDAP Client) I am learning to configure LDAP Server and I am following the  [digital ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-openldap-and-phpldapadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04). phpldapdmin is working fine and I have configured the client also. But when I try to log in to the client using the LDAP user, I get permission denied (public key). Can someone kindly help me with this.

Comment: Probably that's just the last authentication mechanism tried and then was the one that had the error shown. Try posting at least some of what you tried otherwise it'll be hard to get people helping you.

Comment: do you have `by anonymous auth` setting in the slapd.conf ACLs ? A wild guess, but this is often the major reason, besides wrong file permissions on the client or misconfigured key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions in that tutorial are for setting up an LDAP server. They don't cover reconfiguring a system to authenticate against LDAP.

To set your client up so that it can be logged into with LDAP credentials, you'll need to set this up in PAM. There are some instructions on how to do this at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication - in short, you'll need to install `ldap-auth-client`